# How to map nested complex JSON objects and save them to core data?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm having problem with mapping and saving complex nested JSON data to Core data objects. It's meant for reading the data in case of offline mode and caching. JSON also has codes, which represent an id of an object in code list. Nesting depth of object in JSON can be between 5-8 objects.

Example of such (simplified) JSON would be something like this (Person object): https://pastebin.com/nKSFa5cp

Example of code list for relatedPerson:

```
{
    "relatedPerson": [
        {
            "code": 1,
            "description": "Mom"
        },
        {
            "code": 2,
            "description": "Dad"
        },
        {
            "code": 3,
            "description": "Sister"
        }
    ]
}
```

Example of code list for telecomUse:

```
{
    "telecomUse": [
        {
            "code": 1,
            "description": "Home"
        },
        {
            "code": 2,
            "description": "Personal"
        },
        {
            "code": 3,
            "description": "Work"
        }
    ]
}
```

Example of code list for telecomSystem:

```
{
    "telecomSystem": [
        {
            "code": 1,
            "description": "Phone"
        },
        {
            "code": 2,
            "description": "Mobile phone"
        },
        {
            "code": 3,
            "description": "Email"
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I map this code list data to core data object (Person object), at mapping time, with all dependants? Should I save nested object as String and then always map it when i want to read it? Is there any other possibility than manual assigning of codelists and saving it after mapping? The perfect solution, would be an object which would contain all nested objects after mapping and saving. How can this be achieved?

Thanks for your answers

Comment: You want to save the code and description to Core data right.?

Comment: Yes ... but this needs to be saved inside main Person class. I know how to save something to core data. I want to connect main object (Person object) with this codelist objects in coreData (It should be 1:1 relationship)

Comment: The easier way is to decode the JSON into structs and map the structs to the Core Data classes. The more complicated way is to make the Core Data classes adopt `Decodable`

Comment: Something like -

 struct Person {
    let details : [PersonDetails]
}

struct PersonDetails {
    let code: Int
    let description : String
}

Now you can store your person object, which will store code as well?

Comment: more like struct Person { let details : [PersonDetails] } struct PersonDetails { let code: Int let description : String, let phoneUse: PhoneUseType  } struct phoneUseType { let id: Int64, let description: String, let type: PhoneUseCodeList}..  I want to do this at mapping, and have all code list objects inside Person object for easier access to data. Codelist objects should be mapped by designated id.

Comment: *"...codes, which represent an id of an object in code list."* I can't tell what the `code` values mean. Can you add an example of what the code list could look like?

Comment: if you check in Person object (link in posted question above), you have node with key "telecomSystem", with keys "code" and "description". I would like to link the value of key  called called  "code", to its propietary value called "code" in codelist telecomSystem. Codelist is already mapped in core data objects and saved into core data. This should also be done for other code lists objects define above in question.

Comment: @vadian I don't understand your comment. I know can do `trip = try decoder.decode(Trip.self, from:json)`. But when core-data comes into play, what should I do If I have an object like this: `Trip { tripNumber : Int; let driver: Driver; let passenger : passenger; route : Route}`. In core-data I know I can set tripNumber easily, but what about the other properties? Obviously core-data doesn't have a type for `Passenger`, `Driver`, `Route`. Nor I want to create a new NSManagedObject for a subType I don't need. I just care about trips and its properties. Drivers are not important...

Comment: @Honey In all Core Data classes which adopt `Codable` you have to add custom `init(decoder` and `encode(` methods. 1) If there are corresponding Core Data entities for `Driver` and `Route` and each entity adopts `Codable` the objects are also created, you just have to take care of the relationships in the initializer. 2) If you don't need properties / types leave them out in the initializer.

Comment: @vadian I wrote  full question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53989888/do-all-attributes-with-a-custom-type-in-core-data-have-to-be-a-relationship) can you take a look?